# Laravel database petition without a form

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous

## Problem

I want to make petitions to the DB without a form using checkbox, e.g.

I got various divs with info and one checkbox, the checkbox responds to a boolean value in the table, it works, but, I want to make like, if you check/uncheck the input, the value in the DB changes, but I don't wanna make a form or update the entire page every time the user press the checkbox. (I use larravel 9).

### This is my .blade.php

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" @if($table->checked) checked @endif id="checkbox-1"/>
    <label>Checked</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" @if($table->checked) checked @endif id="checkbox-1"/>
    <label>Checked</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" @if($table->checked) checked @endif id="checkbox-1"/>
    <label>Checked</label>
</div>
```

Also, if someone can told me if the code for the checked is fine or it could be "spagetthi" (`@if($check->checked) checked @endif`) (the thing that is inside the input)

## What i know

I know something about async petitions in js, but the thing's that i've done has been with jsons in a built API, no with something that i'm doing, and idk how to send and receive data

Comment: You'll need ajax. When you click your checkbox, the ajax action fires off a request towards your "update checkbox route", but do you really want to fire off an ajax action with every checkbox?

Comment: Hummm. idk, i'll do whatever works, but if there's a better way, you can tell me your idea, probably i'll take it, (i'm new with laravel, so, i'm here to hear advices)